# background video still is low res

Tags: video, background, resolution

I have been experimenting with putting a video into the background of a site, with auto-play off. I am finding that the still presented is of low res. When the video is embed in the usual way the still is high res. Anyone know why we get a low res when its in the background and  how to make it high res. You can see it here if you want to. http://www.dev.ee-web.co.uk/osc/?page_id=239

```
<div id="main-content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="home" data-property="{videoURL: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnLlGVNiQkY', containment: '#home', autoPlay:false, realfullscreen: true, addRaster: false, showControls: false, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}" data-controls="center" data-autoplay="false" class="parallax-bag-yzd ytp-player-yzd row vc_row-fluid no-margin fullwidth light" style="background-image: url(http://www.dev.ee-web.co.uk/osc/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/pool-water-background.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;background-attachment: fixed;background-position: center center;"  data-token="WtcbG"><div class="darker-overlay" style="padding-top: 320px;padding-bottom: 230px; background-color: rgba(, 0.50);">
```

Comment: You should post related codes here.

Comment: some code added - its created by an overkill wp template.